# RAILS 3.2.2.1 > rails assets:precompile LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh/config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, assets, ruby-2.0

rails version 3.2

ruby version 2.0.0  -p451

I'm executing:

```
rails assets:precompile --trace
```

Getting the below error.

rake aborted!

LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh/config

/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in`require'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in `rescue in block in require'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in`require'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/hardik/Projects/mm/project/config/application.rb:9:in`'
/home/hardik/Projects/mm/project/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/hardik/Projects/mm/project/Rakefile:4:in`'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in`load_rakefile'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`block in load_rakefile'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in`load_rakefile'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in`standard_exception_handling'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in`'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in`'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`'

Comment: What is the question? What did you try to solve this issue? Did you try to include this gem to your gemfile `gem 'net-ssh` ?

Comment: @nuaky, Yes I've added 'net-ssh' in my gem file but still same error.